# How do I get Game Centre back on iPad

Tags: ipad

How do I get Game Centre back on iPad?
I have two COC accounts but cannot find Game Centre. I think I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed Game Center from iOS 10.

Comment: There is no longer an app called Game Center. The only version of iOS which allows "deleting" stock apps is iOS 10, and the Game Center app was removed in iOS 10. Therefore the user could not have possibly deleted it from their device in such a way that using the App Store would allow them to get it back.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was exactly thinking about the fact that iOS 10 allows the use to hide apps but I haven't noticed that Apple removed Game Center.